# Kivy 'crashes' without error message ['aborted (disconnected)']

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a multi-file kivy program which has been acting up.
This is a big project of mine and a couple weeks back it started...
Instead of getting a regular exception message like:

`builtins.TypeError: username_is_valid() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'`

(could literally be anything TypeError is just an example)

I simply get:

`aborted (disconnected)`

(see the photo)

[image: 'cr]

I have been able to fix errors without the help of the regular messages until now. It is getting annoying now. Anyone know what could possibly cause this?

Happy to send code, it's just I have no clue what to send... there is a lot.

I can't remember what I changed in the program when it started :/

UPDATE!
I didn't fix it... but I found the problem :)

I traced my versions back to when it started and found the difference between the problem happening and not when an exception was raised.

In my .kv file a text box has its password attribute set to True to hide the text with certain characters. You can choose what character is used with the password_mask attibute. I set password_mask to '•' because it looks nice.

(see photo)

[image]

When password_mask is '•' (or any other unconventional unicode character) it crashes with 'aborted (disconnected)'. Whereas I can make it (for example) '#', '*', ')', 'P', '~', etc... and it works fine.

Looking at this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters , I can use the first table, but not any others.

Any clues as to why this happens and/or how I could fix it?

Comment: Your question really has no useful detail - you even note that the program is large so it's hard even for you to work out what is the relevant part. Debug by trying to produce a minimal runnable example demonstrating the issue, for a start by cutting as much as possible out of your big program.

Comment: @inclement added more info x

Comment: No idea what exactly is going wrong, but it's clearly a bug with use of unicode in kivy.